# React diagram invisible and shows error at <DefaultLinkModel>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I tried using `react-diagrams` library and I'm facing some problems.

Firstly at the line

```
const link = port1.link<DefaultLinkModel>(port2);
```

it shows me a error that

> TypeError: link.addLabel is not a function

and suppose I remove the linking part, the code runs, I get no errors but nothing is seen on the webpage...

here is the code

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import createEngine, {
  DefaultLinkModel,
  DefaultNodeModel,
  DiagramModel
} from "@projectstorm/react-diagrams";

import { CanvasWidget } from "@projectstorm/react-canvas-core";

// create an instance of the engine with all the defaults
const engine = createEngine();

// node 1
const node1 = new DefaultNodeModel({
  name: "Node 1",
  color: "rgb(0,192,255)"
});
node1.setPosition(100, 100);
let port1 = node1.addOutPort("Out");

// node 2
const node2 = new DefaultNodeModel({
  name: "Node 1",
  color: "rgb(0,192,255)"
});
node2.setPosition(100, 100);
let port2 = node2.addOutPort("Out");

//  link them and add a label to the link
const link = port1.link < DefaultLinkModel > port2;
link.addLabel("Hello World!");

const model = new DiagramModel();
model.addAll(node1, node2);
engine.setModel(model);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <CanvasWidget engine={engine} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from "./App"
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .srd-diagram {
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

pls, help me sort this...

Answer (score 0):

*I know this post is too old, but still can be helpful if someone is struggling.*

If you want to add the link between the nodes, try setting the source and target port for the `link`.

```
  const node1 = new DefaultNodeModel({
    name: "Node 1",
    color: "rgb(0,192,255)",
  });
  node1.setPosition(100, 100);
  let port1 = node1.addOutPort("Out");

  const node2 = new DefaultNodeModel({
    name: "Node 2",
    color: "rgb(0,100,255)",
  });
  node2.setPosition(100, 200);
  let port2 = node2.addInPort("In");

  const link = new DefaultLinkModel();
  link.setSourcePort(port1);
  link.setTargetPort(port2);
```

**For the second part:**

> and suppose I remove the linking part, the code runs, I get no errors but nothing is seen on the webpage...

You need to set the canvas height and width to make it visible.

**App.js**

```
<CanvasWidget className="canvas" engine={engine} />
```

**App.css**

```
.canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```